# bypass some domains in exim if condition

Tags: linux, exim

I have this code in /etc/cpanel_exim_system_filter to be able to search and filter spammers in mail body and header. I want to add some domains exclude this rule for example  *@gmail.com, *@mail.com  how can I extend if command to be able to exclude these domains?

```
# SPAM FILTER START
if
# Header Spam
$header_subject: contains "Pharmaceutical"
or $header_subject: contains "Viagra"
or $header_subject: contains "seo"
or $header_subject: contains "Cialis"
or $header_subject: is "The Ultimate Online Pharmaceutical"
# Body Spam
or $message_body: contains "Pharmaceutical"
or $message_body: contains "website audit"
or $message_body: contains "Pay-On-Results"
or $message_body: contains "improve your website"
or $message_body: contains "Viagra"
or $message_body: contains "sex"
or $message_body: contains "seo"
then
  fail text "This message has been rejected by spam filter\n\
             WARNING! THIS MESSAGE HAS NOT BEEN delivered."
        seen finish
endif
# SPAM FILTER FINISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test against the end of the From header, e.g.,

```
$header_from: does not end <whitelisted domain>
```

Leading to something like:

```
if
# Excluded domains
$header_from: does not end "example.com"
and $header_from: does not end "example.org"
...
and (
# Header Spam
$header_subject: contains "Pharmaceutical"
or ...
# Body Spam
or ...
)
then
  fail text "This message has been rejected by spam filter\n\
             WARNING! THIS MESSAGE HAS NOT BEEN delivered."
        seen finish
endif
```

More information: http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch-exim_filter_files.html#SEC23

Comment: thanks for answer josh but this solution doesn't work. I tried gmail as exclusion tried from gmail, result is if I did "Pharmaceutical" as subject system catched and mail Queued. there should be mail delivered without queuing.  I tried mail from gmail without any word it act like spam there is wrong something somewhere.