# Bypass some domains in exim $message_body if condition

Tags: email, exim, filter

I have a custom exim email filter, sample of which is shown below.
Just trying to work out how to bypass the "$message_body contains" part of my filter for specific sender domain names such as ".com" but I still want to log the message id for follow up?

Will the below work?

```
if
 $message_body contains "Hello PayPal" or
 $message_body contains "Dear valued PayPal" or
 $message_body contains "We have a dedicated team" or
 $message_body contains "find love again" or
 $message_body contains "rediscover love" or
 $message_body contains "forward to your positive reply"
 then
  if  
  $sender_address contains ".com" or
  $sender_address contains ".ca"
  then
  logfile /var/log/filter.log 0666
  logwrite "$tod_log Message Body Contains SPAM keywords - Email Sent – Header from: $header_from $message_id" 
  else
  logfile /var/log/filter.log 0666
  logwrite "$tod_log Message Body Contains SPAM keywords – Email Blocked - Header from: $header_from $message_id" 
  freeze 
  endif
endif


if
$header_from contains "igorexdd" or
$header_from contains "secret." or 
$header_from contains "netjobscom" 
then
logfile /var/log/filter.log 0666
 logwrite "$tod_log Email Address Contains Hackers email – Header from:        
$header_from $message_id" 
freeze 
endif
```

Comment: Possible dup - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408487/bypass-some-domains-in-exim-if-condition

Comment: So what happens now?

Comment: it's not a duplicate question, I want to allow certain domains to send emails but if they contain SPAM keywords I what them logged for further investigation if needed.